# Inserting a New Element into provided XML during for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, insert, xsl-fo, xmlnode

I have some XML that I am trying to convert into a report, suitable for printing. So far, everything is going well, except for one part.

This involves the current page number the row in question is currently being outputted to. I am using `<fo:page-number/>` to get the current page number, but I have run head long into a wall about using the information in relation to the current rows siblings after I found out that I could not have a variable with a scope across the `for-each`, let alone be changed.

So, I am currently toying with the idea that on each iteration, the current node being used has a new element (or attribute) introduced that contains the value for `fo:page-number` as it appeared at the time. Then, in the next iteration, I would fetch the element/attribute from `preceding-sibling::`, then test if that the current `fo:page-number` is different from that value.

Sadly, I am not having much luck in finding a way to do this, and all I get from googling is reams of results from w3fools. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic here - you use XSLT to generate XSL-FO, then you use a FO processor to turn the generated XSL-FO into rendered output and it's only at this stage that you know what value a particular `<fo:page-number>` will produce (the XSLT and XSL-FO processors might be part of the same package but conceptually they're two separate phases).  You can't use the output value produced by the `page-number` tag within the XSLT.

Comment: Hmm, thats a shame. Are there any other functions (most likely within fo) to allow the current page number to be yielded as a variable for use in the logic?

Comment: At what stage would you like to use `fo:page-number?` At the stage of XSLT (that is, transforming XML data to XSL-FO), the page number is unknown. But why don't you say a bit more clearly what you're intending to achieve (maybe include sample XML or describe the output) - then, maybe someone could come up with another solution?

Comment: From what I've found, the paging process isn't performed until the XSLT is finished, so it can't be done in this case (as it involves inserting header rows at seemingly arbitrary positions based on the dimensions of the page). This is about inserting additional header rows at the top of every new page, but unless I have something that can accurately measure the amount of space presently occupied by the current content, and the height of the output page area, I can't think of any other ways :s

Comment: Depends on what _exactly_ you intend to do. What is the relationship between a page number value and additional header content being output or not?

Comment: Every new page, the last header that was sent needs to be resent at the top of the next page

Comment: Are we talking about table headers or static-content at the top of pages? If the former, do you mean having several tables spread onto pages and producing the header of the last table on the previous page on top of the current page?

Comment: The table headers can't contain it in this case as the headers have to match a rather exacting specification. The Headers are being inserted as additional rows with a colspan to encompass the whole row, and just make the font bold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of an answer, no, this is not possible.

Basically, repeating headers at the top of every page is possible in XSL-FO, when the attribute `omit-header-at-break` is set to "false". See http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/fo11/a-table-omit-header-at-break-1.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#table-omit-header-at-break for more information on this. I know that this is implemented in Apache FOP, but should also be available with other FO processors.

But of course, this solution assumes that your table header is classified as a header, that is, is semantically a header as opposed to superficially looking like a header while simply being the first row of a table. I understand that the latter is true in your case.

(However, I cannot imagine what kind of specification could keep you from defining the first row of each table as the header which could be repeated.)

Also, while XML data is transformed to XSL-FO, the outcome of a `fo:page-number` instruction is not available yet. Thus, you cannot use it in your stylesheet (this part of the answer is contributed by **@Ian Roberts**). This is because an XSLT stylesheet it processed by an XSLT processor like Saxon that has no concept of FO instructions. `fo:page-number` is interpreted only by the FO processor.

---

The only solution I see is to alter your specification to allow `fo:table-header` elements. By using only table rows and cells, you effectively "sideline" header repetitions after page breaks.